# Using Django For Loop in Drop Down Menu

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to iterate through a list of recommendations previously entered by the user and make each recommendation an item in a drop down list.
[Image of the Code I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xji74.png)

[Image of the Results I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR52x.png)

Comment: Please don't use images to share code, please share it in the question itself, using markdown. Also, the tooltip is hiding some of the code.

Comment: What CSS is applied on the class `dropdown-content`

Answer (score 0):

You can look at django docs for dropdown list(Select Widget).
Maybe it works for you.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#selector-and-checkbox-widgets